# Rows in Pandas fulfill some conditions, assign the values of does conditions to one cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, data-science

I have a Data Frame with some values.

Suppose that does are the values of some stores, and does stores can fulfill some conditions and give them more than one '*state*', but other stores can only fulfill one condition and be assigned with only one '*state*'.

For example:

```
df = DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4],
                'two';[5,6,7,8],
                'three':[9,10,11,12]}
```

and these are my conditions:

```
df.loc[(df.one >= 1) & (df.two <= 7),'State'] = 1
df.loc[(df.one == 1) & (df.two <= 11),'State'] = 2
```

Three rows satisfy the first condition, but only one row satisfy the second condition.

The row that satisfy the two conditions should have in the column '*State*', the state 1 and 2.

The obvious problem is that when the first condition gets assign the DataFrame looks like this:

```
    one two three   State
0   1   5   9        1.0
1   2   6   10       1.0
2   3   7   11       1.0
3   4   8   12       NaN
```

and when the second condition gets assign the Data Frame looks like this:

```
    one two three   State
0   1   5   9        2.0
1   2   6   10       1.0
2   3   7   11       1.0
3   4   8   12       NaN
```

and I want something like this:

```
    one two three   State
0   1   5   9        [1.0,2.0]
1   2   6   10       1.0
2   3   7   11       1.0
3   4   8   12       NaN
```

Here I used a list, but that is the idea.

And then If I do the store in a cell, how I call them, and how I use does cells with more than one value in the column '*State*' for other conditions that depend in that column?

I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky question , I do not recommend you mixing the datatype within one column , as you showed 1st cell is type list , 1 and 2 are type int , then last one is `NaN` (considered as float), in that case why not make them all to list

```
s1=(df.one >= 1) & (df.two <= 7)
s2=(df.one == 1) & (df.two <= 11)
l=[[ z for z in [x,y] if z != 0]for x , y in zip(s1*1,s2*2)]
df['State']=l
df
Out[21]: 
   one  two  three   State
0    1    5      9  [1, 2]
1    2    6     10     [1]
2    3    7     11     [1]
3    4    8     12      []
```